# rosdep refuses to run

Tags: ros-melodic, rosdep, ubuntu

[image: Rosanswers logo]

This is on Ros Melodic on an Nvidia Jetson TX1 with Ubuntu 18.04. I'm trying to install the dependencies for the Zed-Ros-Wrapper.

Did my installation get corrupted? I removed and reinstalled Rosdep but that didn't change this error from coming up.

```
uriah@uriah-jetson:~$ rosdep update
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/usr/bin/rosdep", line 6, in <module>
    from pkg_resources import load_entry_point
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.6/dist-packages/pkg_resources/__init__.py", line 1380
    raise SyntaxError(e) from e
                            ^
SyntaxError: invalid syntax
```

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/408031/rosdep-refuses-to-run/) by [Rodolfo8](https://answers.ros.org/users/18431/rodolfo8/) on ROS Answers with karma: 299 on 2022-10-16

Post score: 0

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [Rodolfo8](https://answers.ros.org/users/18431/rodolfo8/) on 2022-10-16**:
uriah@uriah-jetson:~$ rosdep update

Traceback (most recent call last):

File "/usr/bin/rosdep", line 6, in

```
from pkg_resources import load_entry_point
```

File "/usr/local/lib/python3.6/dist-packages/pkg_resources/**init**.py", line 1380

```
raise SyntaxError(e) from e

                        ^
```

SyntaxError: invalid syntax

**Comment by [Rodolfo8](https://answers.ros.org/users/18431/rodolfo8/) on 2022-10-16**:
It begins to look like the Python 2.7 is trying to use Numpy from Python 3.6 and is getting confused, perhaps

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

sudo pip install -U rosdep rosinstall_generator vcstool rosinstall

pip install -U rosdep rosinstall_generator vcstool rosinstall

pip install --upgrade setuptools

rosdep update

These commands fixed the bad setup, whatever it was!

---

Originally posted by [Rodolfo8](https://answers.ros.org/users/18431/rodolfo8/) with karma: 299 on 2022-10-16

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 0

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [tfoote](https://answers.ros.org/users/3/tfoote/) on 2022-10-16**:
You're mixing python 2 and 3. Pip installing likely overlayed a python3 version of rosdep so you're only using python3 now. Note that you will have to keep everything in your pip environment up to date manually now.